# unable to integrate Neo4j 3 with Gephi 0.9

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I tried all possible ways to connect Neo4j 3.1.1 database with Gephi 0.9.1 but it is not connecting

Environment :
OS: Windows 7 professional
JDK: 1.8
Neo4j: 3.1.1
Gephi: 0.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I have it running using Apoc plugin and it works as expected on windows. 
What you need to do is install Gephi graph streaming plugin, which can be found `Tools --> Plugins --> Available Plugins`

Once you have graph streaming running we utilize `apoc.gephi.add` as in example:

```
match path = (:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)
WITH path LIMIT 1000
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace0', paths) yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

For more info check [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_streaming_data_to_gephi_2).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue as on [Github](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1404)

Possible Solution would be :

> The plugin at https://marketplace.gephi.org works only in Gephi 0.8.2.
>
> The plugin still needs to be adapted to 0.9.1